# Php Google Sheets API v4 not working with sheet names containing single quotes

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-sheets-api

I'm using Googles Sheet API for php to retrieve values from a sheet.  My code seems to work for all sheet names except those that contain a single quote '.  I've tried escaping the single quotes with \' but it doesn't seem to pull the data from the sheet as expected.

My code looks as follows.

```
$sheetId = "1Oz0c3OZN9parxwXU3l9pwWC1wwvmODHQiUz9is50Dy0";
$sheetName = "knijbnjk''''''''''jguvhygvhy";

$escapedSheetName = str_replace("'", "\'", $sheetName);
$range = "'{$escapedSheetName}'!A1:B4";

// returns instance of Google_Service_Sheets with client setup
$service = $this->getSheetService();

$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($sheetId, $range);
var_dump($result);
```

I've tried using a few other variations such as /'  and replacing ' with & quote;  I've tried converting the single quotes to double quotes but so far nothing seems to be working.  Can't seem to find a solution to this problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a [SpreadSheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) this should return a [Spreadsheet resource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet).

```
"sheets": [
{
  object(Sheet)
}
```

This should return a list of all the [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Sheet) within the spreadsheet.

```
"properties": {
    object(SheetProperties)
 },
```

Property within each sheet should contain the information about the sheet.

```
{
  "sheetId": number,
  "title": string,
  "index": number,
  "sheetType": enum(SheetType),
  "gridProperties": {
    object(GridProperties)
  },
  "hidden": boolean,
  "tabColor": {
    object(Color)
  },
  "rightToLeft": boolean,
}
```

My bet is its html encoded ' -> %27

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out you have to escape a single quote ' with another single quote '.

So solution is

```
$escapedSheetName = str_replace("'", "''", $sheetName);
```

So weird.